# showing my models value on view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

im new in codeigniter and get some trouble with my function

here is my model

```
public function kode_unik(){
$q = $this->db->query("select MAX(RIGHT(id_obat,5)) as code_max from obat");
        $code = "";
        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            foreach($q->result() as $cd){
                $tmp = ((int)$cd->code_max)+1;
                $hitung = strlen($tmp);
                if ($hitung == 1 ){
                    $a = "0000".$tmp;
                } elseif ($hitung == 2) {
                    $a = "000".$tmp;
                }elseif ($hitung == 3) {
                    $a = "00".$tmp;
                }elseif ($hitung == 4) {
                    $a = "0".$tmp;
                }else{
                    $a = $tmp;
                }

                $code = sprintf("%s", $a);
            }
        }else{
            $code = "0001";
        }
        $kodenyami = "E".$code;
        return $kodenyami;
    }
```

and then i wanna get the result of my models to show in my view. 
here is my controller

```
public function add_data()
    {   
        $this->load->helper( array('fungsidate', 'rupiah', 'url') );
        $this->load->model('obat');
        $this->load->database();
        $data['a'] = $this->obat->tampil_data();
        $data['b'] = $this->obat->kode_unik();
        $componen = array(
           "header" => $this->load->view("admin/header", array(), true),
           "sidebar" => $this->load->view("admin/sidebar", array(), true), 
           "content" => $this->load->view("admin/add_obat", array("data" => $data), true)
          );
        $this->load->view('admin/index', $componen);
    }
```

and my view goes here.

```
                  <i class="fa fa-medkit fa-5x"></i></div>
               <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
     line20->  <div class="huge"><?php echo $b; ?></div>
         <div>ID Obat</div>
```

the code give me an errors Message: Undefined variable: b

just don't know how to put the value of my models $kode_unik into my view ..

thanks

Comment: Although I think it would produce different message, you have different names in controller and model (`kodeunik()` vs. `kode_unik()`).

Comment: Part of which view file you posted above: `admin/index` or `admin/add_obat`?

Comment: admin/add_obat is a part of admin/index and my model shold be show in admin/add_obat

Comment: Part starting with `<i class="fa fa-medkit fa-5x"></i>` is in `admin/add_obat` or in `admin/index`?

Comment: it starts in admin/add_obat

Comment: If you want to use it in that file, pass `"content" => $this->load->view("admin/add_obat", $data, true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data is already an array. Maybe like this :

"content" => $this->load->view("admin/add_obat", $data, TRUE)

CodeIgniter will extract the keys in $data so you will be able to use them in your view as $b

BTW instead of passing array() as a parameter of the load->view you can use NULL

P.S If you set the last parameter to TRUE, you will return the populated content of that view as a String (HTML in that case)

Here is something to start with :

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::construct();

    $this->load->helper(‘array(‘fungsidate’, ‘rupiah’, ‘url’);
    $this->load->model(‘obat’);
    $this->load->database();   // Should be already loaded depending on your config
}

public function add_data() {
    // Set the data
    $data[‘a’] = $this->obat->tampil_data();
    $data[‘b’] = $this->obat->kodeunik();

    // Load the views
    $componen = array(
    ‘header’ => $this->load->view(‘admin/header’, NULL, TRUE);
    ‘sidebar’ => $this->load->view(‘admin/sidebar’, NULL, TRUE);
    ‘content’ => $this->load->view(‘admin/add_obat', $data, TRUE);
    );
    $this->load->view(‘admin/index’ ,$componen);
}
```

From what I understand about your code, in your templates you will need to echo the array keys

in admin/header you will echo $header;
in admin/sidebar you will echo $sidebar;
in admin/add_obat you will need to echo $content

and then you admin/index should be populated. I won’t do that if I were you to be honest I would probably load each template as is instead of outputting them as HTML string inside the final index. I don’t know exactly how you did your structure so it’s kinda hard for me to guess well. But in my case I would have use something like this instead of the componen array

```
public function add_data() {
    // Set the data
    $data[‘a’] = $this->obat->tampil_data();
    $data[‘b’] = $this->obat->kodeunik();

    // Load the views
    $this->load->view(‘admin/header’);
    $this->load->view(‘admin/sidebar’);
    $this->load->view(‘admin/add_obat, $data); // This should be the body template of your page
    $this->load->view(‘admin/footer’); // I guess you have a footer template
}
```

I hope this will help you!